# How to plot the mean of a 2d list with some empty elements

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How can I plot the mean of such a list: http://pastebin.com/dNjeR4WC
which contains an alternating number of elements in the sublists and some sublists that are empty and should not be considered in the plot (the corresponding mean does not exist).

Example:

```
{{},{},{},{1,2},{1,2,3},{4,5},{3,4,5,6,7},{},{2,3,4,5,6},{6}}
```

For the upper example I would like to plot:

```
{{},{},{},Mean[{1,2}],Mean[{1,2,3}],Mean[{4,5}],Mean[{3,4,5,6,7}],{},
Mean[{2,3,4,5,6}],Mean[{6}]}
```

Comment: Whatever does the mean of such a list mean? The mean of each nonempty list? The mean of all the numbers in that list? Some clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the `Mean` of every non-empty sublist?  `list // DeleteCases[{}] // Map[Mean]` Or the mean of all the numbers?
 `list // DeleteCases[{}] // Flatten // Mean`

Comment: @J. M.: please see the example above ...

Comment: So what about `{{}, {}, {}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {}, {2, 3, 4,
      5, 6}, {6}} // DeleteCases[{}] // Map[Mean] // ListPlot`?

Comment: So, `If[# =!= {}, Mean[#], #] & /@ list`?

Comment: @JasonB: I would like to show no points for x values: 1,2,3,8

Comment: Like `Table[Mean[a[[i]]], {i, Length[a]}] /. Mean[{}] -> {}`?

Comment: @J. M.: Yes that is the list of mean values `{{}, {}, {}, 3/2, 2, 9/2, 5, {}, 4, 6}`, but how can I plot it (no points for empty elements)?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{{}, {}, {}, 3/2, 2, 9/2, 5, {}, 4, 6} /. {} -> Missing[]]`?

Comment: @J. M. yes that is the solution ... perfect ... please put it into an answer with my pastebin data if this question is not duplicate.

Comment: If you can assemble a complete solution from the bits and pieces I gave, I would encourage you to write your own answer instead.

Comment: I did not know that this also works: `ListLinePlot[{, , , 3/2, 2, 9/2, 5, , 4, 6}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{}, {}, {}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7}, {}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {6}};
list // MapIndexed[If[#1 != {}, {First@#2, Mean@#1}] &] // 
  DeleteCases[Null] // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here it is with the larger data set

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/dNjeR4WC" // 
   MapIndexed[If[#1 != {}, {First@#2, Mean@#1}] &] // 
  DeleteCases[Null] // ListPlot
```

Or, with a slightly shorter syntax (thanks to J.M. for pointing it out)

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/dNjeR4WC" // Map[Mean] // 
  ReplaceAll[_Mean :> Missing] // ListPlot
```

both of which give the same result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you show it also for the pastebin data?

Comment: Sure thing! (minimum character count for comment reached now)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = {{}, {}, {}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {6}}
Mean /@ Select[data, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]
```

Alternativly, here is a version proposed by *@JasonB*

```
data // Select[Not@*EqualTo[{}]] // Map[Mean]
```

**Output**

> {3/2, 2, 9/2, 5, 4, 6}

Comment: It's slightly longer than your version, but I'm really enjoying using postfix notation with operator forms, so you could write that as `data // Select[Not@*EqualTo[{}]] // Map[Mean]`

Comment: Thanks @JasonB, I will add it to this answer as an alternative form! I am still trying to wrap my hand around all the syntax nuances in wolfram language. I find it particularly mind bending when writing code following rule-based approach: s